# SparQl/Gephi queries for sourcing stylistic origins and subgenres for music genres of the African Diaspora

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, gephi

I'm conducting research on music genres of the African Diaspora, and inputting data into Gephi to visualize the connections. Following the [List of Musical Genres of the African Diaspora](https://dbpedia.org/page/List_of_musical_genres_of_the_African_diaspora), I'm trying to source data pertaining to the stylistic origins as well as subgenres of the genres listed.

Unfortunately, the query I'm using in SparQl doesn't work when I try to obtain stylistic origins and subgenres for Blues, Jazz, Afrobeat, Soca, and a few others.

I wondered if anybody here might have any insight/suggestions for revising the recipe to obtain that information? The digital librarian who provided me with this query also seems to be stumped and he suggested I reach out to this community. Any information would be helpful!

To obtain the list of music genres from the [List of musical genres of the African diaspora](https://dbpedia.org/page/List_of_musical_genres_of_the_African_diaspora) including genre id, I use the following recipe:

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>

SELECT ?geId ?genre

WHERE
{
:List_of_musical_genres_of_the_African_diaspora dbo:wikiPageWikiLink ?genre .
?genre dbo:wikiPageID ?geId .
FILTER (?genre != <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Puerto_Rico>) .
}
```

After obtaining ID and Labels for each genre, I use the following complex query to obtain IDs and labels, stylistic origins, and music subgenres for each single genre:

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>

SELECT ?stOrId ?stylisticOrigin ?stOrLabelValue ?geId ?genre ?geLabelValue ?muSuId ?musicSubgenre ?muSuLabelValue

WHERE {
:List_of_musical_genres_of_the_African_diaspora dbo:wikiPageWikiLink ?genre .
?genre dbo:stylisticOrigin ?stylisticOrigin .
?genre dbo:wikiPageID ?geId .
?genre rdfs:label ?geLabel .
?genre dbo:musicSubgenre ?musicSubgenre .
?stylisticOrigin dbo:wikiPageID ?stOrId .
?stylisticOrigin rdfs:label ?stOrLabel .
?musicSubgenre dbo:wikiPageID ?muSuId .
?musicSubgenre rdfs:label ?muSuLabel .
FILTER (?geId = 28261) .
FILTER (LANG(?geLabel) = "en").
BIND(STR(?geLabel) AS ?geLabelValue).
FILTER (LANG(?stOrLabel) = "en").
BIND(STR(?stOrLabel) AS ?stOrLabelValue).
FILTER (LANG(?muSuLabel) = "en").
BIND(STR(?muSuLabel) AS ?muSuLabelValue).
}
```

For some reason, Blues, Jazz, Afrobeat, Soca, and a few others are just wired differently I suspect and so I am having trouble getting the data.

Comment: the data in DBpedia is heterogenous - if your check for example Blues, there is no `musicSubgenre` in the data - in the case you have to check for alternative properties or the data simply doesn't exist. To handle optional data you can use `OPTIONAL` in SPARQL and avoid missing results.